# Particle in a Box and Bohr Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

What is the difference between a particle in a box and an electron in the Bohr model? I am a bit confused because of the different Energy solution for different states. The Energy of the Patricle in the box goes with $n^2$ while in the energy in the Bohr model declines with $1/n^2$.

Comment: What are the assumptions involved which lead to the results?

Comment: The potential function is different in each case.

Comment: ah i see, in the bohr model the electric potential is used while in the particle in the box,  has no potential inside the box , but is bound through the walls?

Comment: They are incomparable things. Bohr model describes electrons in an atom and the particle in a box has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The $V\propto r^{-1}$ potential gives energy level spacing that *decreases* with energy (eventually becoming a continuum for the unbound states).  The harmonic potential $V\propto r^2$ gives evenly spaced energy levels.  The particle in a box potential gives energy level spacing that *increases* with energy.  See a pattern?

Comment: The energy in the Bohr model doesn't 'decline' with growing $n$; instead, it *grows*, as $-1/n^2$ (i.e. it becomes less negative) with growing $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Bohr model of an atom (which has a electric potential V∝1/r)?

I so, these are two totally different setups where an electron oscillates.

The electron in a box only has bound states, and essentially it is similar to a free particle except for restrictions at the endpoints (box edges).

The bound states of the Bohr model of the atom do go like $1/n^2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom or any QM text book for details.